# Why is my furnace burner going out after 30 seconds?

Tags: furnace

My furnace pilot is throwing a flame on the flame sensor (or what I believe it to be). The furnace burner is igniting and staying lit for about 30 seconds, then the burner goes out and the blower starts running. If anyone could help me possibly troubleshoot this to the point where I can get heat in my house tonight that would be great.

[image: furnace pilot touching flame sensor]

Comment: What make and model is your furnace?

Comment: Remove the flame sensor and clean it till you have shiny metal.

Comment: **Do not recommend**, remove the wires from the over temperature sensor just to see if it is working now and to know if it needs replacement.

Comment: Make is by heat controller out of Jackson Michigan

Comment: The model number is CN3D104F29789657

Comment: @Ruskes I don’t know how to get to that, if my research is correct it is above the burners. The only access I have is where I took the picture from. How would I be able to access the the wires in order to remove them

Comment: It sounds like the bonnet sensor has failed. This is just a guess as I could not find anything on your furnace.

Comment: I do not know your model, do you know how the over temp sensor look like ?

Comment: @Ruskes are you talking about the metal sensor that’s shaped like an L?

Comment: it could be or it is round, in any case it has two wires

Comment: is there an error code flashing on your control board?  does sound like the flame sensor though...   i pulled mine out and used sandpaper (apparently you should only use emory cloth) but it worked for 6 months before I decided to swap it for a new one just in case I did damage it.

Comment: This happened to me a while back.  Turned out to be a clogged condensation drain hose.   While this is likely not your problem, it's worth checking.

Answer (score 1):

Change out thermocouple. It’s not generating enough millivolts to keep gas valve open to keep burners on.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I can attest it is true. After routine maintenance, which replaced my old yet functioning thermal couple, my pilot wouldn't stay on. The technician had to come back and replace the defective thermal couple.